# How to identify dac_override cause on Android?

Tags: android, selinux

I am working on some Android customizations and an app I am writing causes a `dac_override` which looks like so in dmesg:

```
type=1400 audit(499405.329:16): avc: denied { dac_override } for 
pid=1103 comm="my_tool" capability=1 scontext=u:r:my_tool:s0
tcontext=u:r:my_tool:s0 tclass=capability permissive=1
```

I know the executable that is causing the problem (it's `my_tool`) and I know that `dac_override` means that the executable doesn't have traditional linux permissions to perform some operation, but I don't know which operation was attempted and which file it was attempted on. How can I find out?

Also as a side question I assume by the name and the behavior that `dac_override` means that SELinux has the capability to override traditional linux permission violations?

Comment: so were you able to find a way?

Comment: I could not find an obvious solution, I had to use intuition. I would still like appreciate if anyone has a proper scientific solution.

Answer (score 1):

The systematic way would be to

1) Set SELinux to enforcing via `setenforce 1`. The SELinux violation should then make the corresponding syscall in `my_tool` fail. You can use `getenforce` to verify this succeeded.

2) Run your `my_tool` with `strace` to identify the failing syscall, e.g. `strace my_tool 2>&1 | grep '= -'`.

In my case, I have the following violation: `type=1400 msg=audit(4816808.488:3): avc: denied { dac_override } for pid=123 comm="my_tool" capability=1 scontext=u:r:my_tool:s0 tcontext=u:r:my_tool:s0 tclass=capability permissive=0`

Running `strace my_tool 2>&1 | grep '= -'` gives

`openat(AT_FDCWD, "/some/file", some_mode) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)`

Using `ls -l /some/file` confirms the file is owned by the `system` user whereas `my_tool` is running as `root` and that the DAC permissions of this file do not intend to allow access by other users. Of course, the `root` user bypasses this restrictions, but it generates the `dac_overwrite` violation in SELinux ([reference](https://danwalsh.livejournal.com/79643.html)). So concerning your last question: SELinux does not allow to bypass traditional DAC permissions, but it can be used to enforce them even for the `root` user.

Of course, the effectiveness of this approach to some extend depends on the complexity of `my_tool`, i.e. how many other failing syscalls it deals with during normal operation.

Answer (score 0):

The generic advice to [enable full syscall auditing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/659842/1131) to get some path information with such AVCs. However, android doesn't seem to support it. Thus, tracing syscalls with `strace` or `perf trace` and looking for failed file related ones is the next best thing.

### See also

[Debugging DAC_OVERRIDE](https://sx.ix5.org/info/post/debugging-dac_override/) (on Android), published 2019, which describes modifying the android kernel to get some call-stacks when the AVC happens. Which is of course a bit intrusive and only seems to be worthwhile if you can't use `perf` - since with `perf` who could just install a probe to get similar information.